# What is the proper procedure to alert a thread the stop what it's doing and return before exiting?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

What is the proper procedure to alert a running thread to stop what it's doing and return before exiting the application?

```
protected Thread T;
protected static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
protected static bool ThreadRunning = true;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    T = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
    T.Start();
}

private void ThreadFunc()
{
    while (ThreadRunning)
    {
        // Do stuff
        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }
    mre.Set();
}

private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadRunning = false;
    mre.WaitOne();
    mre.Close();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Initially I had my code setup like the above. My thinking for how exit properly is as follows:

1. Set `ThreadRunning = false` so that the next time thread T checks that variable it knows to stop.
2. Call `mre.WaitOne()` to wait for thread T to say it's actually done via it calling `mre.Set()`.
3. If so, then unblock and continue, dispose of mre (`mre.Close()`) and exit.

For some reason the above setup sometimes fails after the exit button is clicked and the whole form becomes inactive.

My new setup is below but doesn't seem entirely correct to me, for instance `mre.Set()` isn't going to wait for anything and `Application.Exit()` is immediately after it. I'm just waiting for it to fail like before, but so far it hasn't.

```
protected Thread T;
protected static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
protected static bool ThreadRunning = true;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    T = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
    T.Start();
}

private void ThreadFunc()
{
    while (ThreadRunning)
    {
        // Do stuff
        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }
    mre.WaitOne();
    mre.Close();
}

private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ThreadRunning = false;
    mre.Set();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: `new Thread` is for fire-and-forget threads which you do not cancel, get information from, or even care if they are running. If you want to get information back or cancel the thread you should be using [async/await](http://msdn.com/async).

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57144771/how-to-make-a-method-thread-safe .in last answer your question answered

Comment: A *bool* is not a thread synchronization object, like ManualResetEvent .  "Certain circumstances" are the Release build of your app, allowing the read of the bool variable to be optimized away.  There are multiple ways to fix this, like using MRE instead of a bool, but it tends to help to uplift the threading interaction.  How to do this correctly for BackgroundWorker is the subject of [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731384/how-to-stop-backgroundworker-on-forms-closing-event).

Comment: @Nux, have you managed to resolve an issue?

Comment: @fenixil Yes, I took into consideration your answer and OlivierRogier's.

Comment: @Nux this resource is community driven, so don't hesitate to vote for the answers that are helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

UI hangs because you blocks UI thread with `mre.WaitOne();`. 
If you need to wait until thread exits, you can use its [IsAlive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isalive?view=netframework-4.8) property and process application messages, you don't need application events for that:

```
while(_t.IsAlive)
  Application.DoEvents();
```

There are 2 thread cancelation aproaches:

- [cooperative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) - code that is executed by thread knows that it could be cancelled and cancellation handled gracefuly, that's what you try to do here.
- imperative - force thread to stop - call `Thread.Abort`  or `Interrupt`, [don't use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices) that.

As @HansPassant mentioned, `bool` is not the best option because that compiler may optimize that and bool value could be cached and its change may not be handled by looping thread. You need to make it at least `volatile` or just refactor code to use `CancellationSource`.

Given what your thread is doing, perhaps `BackgroundWorker`, `Timer` or Producer/Consumer pattern is a better alternative to `Thread`, but I have too little context to recommend anything. Also it works well only if you have only 1 instance of `Form1` in the application, if you have multiform application and user can open several `Form1` forms, you'll have problems.

General recommendation, if you can work with instance level fields, please do that, don't use static.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for 40 msec between doing stuff creates no problems, but what if you had to wait 5 sec or more? Then canceling *between* each waiting would be problematic, and the right thing to do would be to cancel *the awaiting itself*. It is fairly easy to do it actually. Just replace `Thread.Sleep(40)` with `Task.Delay(40, token).Wait()` where `token` is a [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken).

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    protected readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    protected readonly Thread _thread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadFunc()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Do stuff here
                Task.Delay(40, _cts.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Ignore cancellation exception
        }
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        this.Visible = false; // Hide the form before blocking the UI
        _thread.Join(5000); // Wait the thread to finish, but no more than 5 sec
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Personally I would prefer to do the background job using a `Task` instead of a `Thread`, because it is more easily awaited without blocking the UI. This task would run lazily using thread-pool threads. The drawback is that the stuff that runs every 40 msec would not always run in the same thread, so I could have thread-safety issues to resolve.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    protected readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    protected readonly Task _task;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _task = Task.Run(TaskFunc);
        this.FormClosing += Form_FormClosing;
    }

    private async Task TaskFunc()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Do async stuff here, using _cts.Token if possible
                // The stuff will run in thread-pool threads
                await Task.Delay(40, _cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Ignore cancellation exception
        }
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private async void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_task == null || _task.IsCompleted) return;
        e.Cancel = true;
        _cts.Cancel();
        this.Visible = false; // Or give feedback that the form is closing
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(_task, Task.Delay(5000));
        if (completedTask != _task) Debug.WriteLine("Task refuses to die");
        _task = null;
        await Task.Yield(); // To ensure that Close won't be called synchronously
        this.Close(); // After await we are back in the UI thread
    }
}
```